# Illustrator: Cut / Delete circle shapes from multiple layers

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying to cut a circle shape from two layers. The top layer is the circle layer, below a yellow box and background layer black. After the circle is cutted / deleted the background layer will get a red stroke.

**My work**

[image]

**Want to do like**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question, try this:

#### 1. Cut out shapes using Pathfinder

[image]

1. Position your objects
2. Select the two circles
3. Open the [Pathfinder panel](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/combining-objects.html#pathfinder) (<kbd>Window</kbd> > <kbd>Pathfinder</kbd>)
4. Group the circles (<kbd>Object</kbd> > <kbd>Group</kbd>) or click the “Unite” button (<kbd>option</kbd> + click to make compound shape; click “Expand” button to create a compound path)
5. With the two circles (now one Group) selected, <kbd>shift</kbd> + click the background rectangle
6. Click the Pathfinder’s “Minus Front” button

#### 2. Bonus! Round corners

[image]

1. Switch to the [Pen Tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/drawing-pen-pencil-or-flare.html)
2. Hold down <kbd>Command</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd> on Windows
3. Click and drag across the top of your rectangle to select the top two points
4. Hold down <kbd>Command</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd> on Windows and “grab” one of the corner radius circles
5. Drag downwards to produce a rounded corner
6. Optionally, double click on one of the corner radius circles to get a dialog window with options:

   [image]

**If this answers your question, please take the time to up-vote or mark as the “accepted answer”.**

Comment: But I have 2 layers! Have to cut with the same size the yellow and black layers! I want to stroke it like the image below of mine. Just do the same like in the image.